# How to iterate and loop through a dataframe one row at a time?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

Data Set:

```
First_Name Last_Name Location
Green White US
Lew Edward UK
Ravi Kumar India
Naveen Reddy France
Yi Ling Singapore
Xin Yi Taiwan
Ryan Nicholas Singapore
```

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv (r'data.csv')

def name():
    for row in df.iterrows():
        name1 = df['First_name']
        name2 = df['Last_name']
        location = df['Location']

while True:
    print(name)
```

Comments:

Above code is returning the complete data frame and it looks like it looping all the `df` rows in one go.
Is there a way to just loop one row in a loop?

Example:

```
loop1 - Green White US
loop2 - Lew Edward UK
loop3 - Ravi Kumar India
```

Comment: **df['First_name']**, it returns the values for columns "First_name". You need to use the `row` from the for loop to get the desired data

Comment: This is not the correct way to split a column in pandas.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', sep='\\s+')` the separators for the data are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

`iterrows()` allows to iterate over the tuples index, row

Here is a quick solution to iterating all over the data frame:

```
def names():
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        name1 = row['First_name']
        name2 = row['Last_name']
        location = row['Location']
        print('{} {} {}'.format(name1, name2, location))


names()
```